# How can increase select query row with for loop in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that I pull with select and returns one line at a time.
I wanted this query to write two row to the declared v_output_piece_table by bulk collect it twice with the for loop.But I saw that it wrote a single row in the v_output_piece_table.

I want it to rotate two rows now depending on the situation inside he for loop but this will depend on a variable in future.

```
 v_output_piece_table tbl_met_output_coil; 
begin
    FOR sayac IN 1..2 
            loop
                SELECTSUBSTR (sl.task_job_id, 1, 12) AS schedule_id,
                       DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY sc.seq) AS coil_seq,
                          round(p.ACTUAL_WEIGHT/3,3)
                          AS weight,
                       scd.so_id,
                       scd.so_line_id
                  BULK COLLECT
                  INTO v_output_piece_table
                  FROM sch_line            sl,
                       sch_input_material  sim,
                       sch_input_piece     sip,
                       sch_output_material som,
                       sch_cut             sc,
                       sch_cut_detail      scd,
                       piece               P
                 WHERE sl.task_job_id = 180078
                   AND sl.sch_line_num_id = sim.sch_line_num_id
                   AND sl.sch_line_num_id = som.sch_line_num_id
                   AND som.output_mat_num_id = sc.output_mat_num_id
                   AND sc.schc_cut_num_id = scd.schc_cut_num_id
                   AND sim.input_mat_num_id = sip.input_mat_num_id
                   AND sip.piece_num_id = P.piece_num_id
                 ORDER BY sl.seq, sim.seq, sip.seq;
                END LOOP;
end;
```

QUERY output :

```
|SCHEDULE_ID|   |L3_OUTPUT_CNT| |EN_COIL_ID|    |COIL_SEQ|  |WEIGHT|    |SO_ID| |SO_LINE_ID|    
| 180078    |   |      1      | |   21TT   |    |    1   |  |39663 |    |  2  | |    3     |
```

What I want:

```
 |SCHEDULE_ID|   |EN_COIL_ID|    |COIL_SEQ| |WEIGHT|    |SO_ID| |SO_LINE_ID|    
 | 180078   |    |   21TT   |    |   1   |  |39663 |    |  2  | |    3     |
 | 180078   |    |   21TT   |    |   2   |  |39663 |    |  2  | |    3     |
```

How can I get the output I want ?

Comment: You are running the query to fill v_output_piece_table. Then you run the query again and fill v_output_piece_table again. Thus the new result relaces the old result. So the problem is that the array gets not extended as you hoped, but replaced. My question, though: As you run the same query, how do you expect to get two different values for COIL_SEQ in your result?

Comment: I understand that the problem is that the array gets not extended , so coil _ seq not get two different values and neither is row count. So how can I expand my output table ?

Comment: Even if the array got extended, your tables would still have the same content and `DENSE_RANK` would return the same number. Why do you expect to get another number the second time you run the query?

Comment: because what I want is to return two rows as much as the number of loops as in table below.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But if you select the same data twice, how can you expect one column to be different? By what magic do you think that `COIL_SEQ` changes its value the second time you run the query? We cannot answer how to solve this, because our solution would of course get you the same data twice. Both rows would have the same `COIL_SEQ`. Do you maybe want to take the sayac into the calculation somehow in order to get different results? If so, how?

Comment: On a side note: Who taught you that **join syntax**? It was replaced by explicit joins about **30 years ago** (well, a little less in Oracle). Please get rid of those ugly error prone comma separated joins and switch to explicit joins (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, ...). And, well, better quit the class, tutorial or book you are using.

Comment: if we can extend the query we can give sayac value in seq ?

Comment: It would be okay to replace `DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY sc.seq) AS coil_seq` by `sayac AS coil_seq`?

Comment: so the real question is how to extend the v_output_table ?

Comment: No, the first question is how to get two different values into COIL_SEQ. Once this is answered, we can start thinking about how to produce the rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy to do if you cross join your query with a 2 line query:

```
WITH your_query AS (SELECT SUBSTR (sl.task_job_id, 1, 12) AS schedule_id,
                           round(p.ACTUAL_WEIGHT/3,3) AS weight,
                           scd.so_id,
                           scd.so_line_id,
                           sl.seq sl_seq,
                           sim.seq sim_seq,
                           sip.seq sip_seq
                      BULK COLLECT
                      INTO v_output_piece_table
                      FROM sch_line            sl,
                           sch_input_material  sim,
                           sch_input_piece     sip,
                           sch_output_material som,
                           sch_cut             sc,
                           sch_cut_detail      scd,
                           piece               P
                     WHERE sl.task_job_id = 180078
                       AND sl.sch_line_num_id = sim.sch_line_num_id
                       AND sl.sch_line_num_id = som.sch_line_num_id
                       AND som.output_mat_num_id = sc.output_mat_num_id
                       AND sc.schc_cut_num_id = scd.schc_cut_num_id
                       AND sim.input_mat_num_id = sip.input_mat_num_id
                       AND sip.piece_num_id = P.piece_num_id),
       dummy AS (SELECT LEVEL ID
                 FROM   dual
                 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2)
SELECT yt.schedule_id,
       d.id coil_seq,
       yt.weight,
       yt.so_id,
       yt.so_line_id
FROM   your_query yt
       CROSS JOIN dummy d
ORDER BY yt.sl_seq,
         yt.sim_seq,
         yt.sip_seq,
         d.id;
```

The dual table is a special table that only contains one row and one column, and so you can use it to generate rows. You could have simply union'd two rows together in the dummy subquery, e.g.:

```
   dummy AS (SELECT 1 ID FROM dual
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 ID FROM dual)
```

but I prefer using the hierarchical trick using `connect by` since it's easy to amend if in the future you need to triplicate (or more!) the rows.